# "adb devices" shows empty list

Tags: android, adb

I've installed Google USB Driver and I've typed VID to `c:\Users\%USERNAME%\.android\adb_usb.ini` (`0x12D1`), still `List of devices attached` is empty.

Windows 7 x64, Huawei U8110, Android 2.2, phone is enabled for debugging.

What's wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You can try updating your driver software first.

1. Go to Device Manager
2. Check in "Other devices" if you have Android
3. Right click Android and "Update Driver Software"
4. You can browse for drivers then select "Android ADB Interface"

After updating, your `adb devices` should display.

Or try installing this driver:

http://download.clockworkmod.com/test/UniversalAdbDriverSetup6.msi

Comment: It's already been like that, still nothing.